# How do I prevent the screen from blanking?

Tags: linux, console, screensaver

I am running 12.04 Ubuntu Server and my screen blanks after some time. I am unable to unblank it without power cycling the computer.

I can however log in via `ssh` and type who see that the `tty1` terminal is active.

I have asked this question here twice before and have accepted the solutions that worked at that time.

- using `console-tools`
- editing `/etc/kbd/config`

These no longer work. How do I prevent Ubuntu Server from blanking the screen? Or at least unblank it without a power cycle?

I am not using X.

Comment: What do you mean by "These no longer work."? What happened?

Comment: Which settings in `/etc/kbd/config` did you change?

Answer (score 1):

run the following on system startup (e.g. on Debian based systems i put it into `/etc/rc.local`)

```
 setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
```

Comment: Before I put that in `rc.local`, I ran that command at the terminal after a power cycle (using sudo). and now my screen is off. It did not work.

Answer (score -1):

This should not be happening. Maybe you have defective hardware that slowly overheats and then blanks? Timing how long it takes exactly after a warm reboot to blank and a cold one could tell you. The cold one (machine off for at least 10 Minutes) should take a bit longer.

Comment: Does not happen with a different OS!